# PrimenG radio button icons not shown

Tags: angular, primeng, primeicons

I am trying to have a radio button displayed next to a question I will be asking a user. I am using PrimeNg and when I compile my code I do not get the empty circle next to my radio fields

I have installed primeicons aswell

Code for radio buttons

```html
<p>
    I have enough hours to cover these Absences*
</p>
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-radioButton
        name="group1"
        value="YES"
        label="YES"
        [(ngModel)]="YES"
        inputId="YES"
    ></p-radioButton>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-radioButton
        name="group1"
        value="NO"
        label="NO"
        [(ngModel)]="NO"
        inputId="NO"
    ></p-radioButton>
</div>
```

Here is what is outputted on my screen

[image: Displayed code]

Comment: Did you import the RadioButtonModule of primeng?  import {RadioButtonModule} from 'primeng/radiobutton';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sodjqd) of your code with visible icons.

Make sure that styles for both theme and icons are used in `styles.css` or in `angular.json` as recommended in [Getting Started](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) guide.